# C# setting a tooltip to a <asp:Label> or a <asp:Literal>

Tags: c#, asp.net

What's the best way to ADD a TOOLTIP to either a Label or a Literal from the Code Behind of a C# ASP.NET site ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [WebControl.ToolTip Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tooltip.aspx) to set tool tip on Label control.

```
Label1.ToolTip = "Your text as tooltip";
```

Comment: @Developer, You don't have to do anything, its just a property and will be available in your code behind. Just try it in visual studio.

Comment: yep..I was working all this time with a Literal and never thought to use a Label. When I came over here and typed the question, I somehow thought about the Label. Thanks Habib !!

Answer (score 13):

I recommend against using WebControls, I advocate using HtmlControls instead, as they provide a more direct representation of the generated output HTML.

Note that `asp:Literal` is not a WebControl, despite being in the `WebControls` namespace, so it lacks many of the forms-based properties like `ToolTip`.

The `ToolTip` property is actually a front for the HTML `title=""` attribute, which can be applied to any visible element. If you're using `Literal` then just ensure that you have the `title="tip text goes here"` attribute in your markup.

If you're using HtmlControls then you can use the `Attributes` collection, like so:

```
HtmlControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
div.Attributes["title"] = "tooltip text here";
```

Comment: so u suggesting to add a DIV around it?